# how to remove unwanted characters from data

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I need to write a function which identifies and removes the "*" character after some numeric values in a vector. I also need  that the resultant vector is a numeric vector.

```
c("21,34,99*", "56,90*", "45*")
```

I need to remove "`*`" which is unwanted.

I want to write function so whenever such data cleaning requirement I can use function and pass certain parameters.

Comment: i tried to edit your post but my 50K plus rep on SO-proper counts for naught here. Anyway, consider deleting this and posting it to SO-proper with what you've tried. Right now, you're asking for someone to write code for you so you can take credit for it where you work or school and that's not cool.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, I approved your edit, but you are right in that this question belongs on SO.  FYI, you can still flag for closure at your current rep level.

Comment: I'm gd with only being a 1st class citizen on SO @StephenRauch :-)

Comment: Are you familiar with regular expressions?

Comment: Well you can just split your vector on basis of * as it's coming at the end or as @media said, regex is the best

Comment: Why not just `lapply(strsplit(gsub("\\*","",x),","),as.numeric)`?

Answer (score 1):

Should have been posted in SO as others rightly pointed out.

Simple solution would be to:

1. Split on '*' and select the first part of the split.
2. Apply *(1)* over list items and return a vector.

   ```
   x <- c("21,34,99*", "56,90*", "45*")               #test case

   data_clean <- function(x) sapply (strsplit(x , '[*]' ), `[` , 1)
   data_clean(x)
   ```